# Botão não abre modal JS

Tags: javascript

Quando clicar em um dos botões da página um modal com um formulário deve abrir.
Mas cada botão deve conter um form diferente. Utilizei o seguinte codigo:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
// teste para ocultar menu
var ocultar = document.getElementById('header');

//Obter o modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

//Obter o botão que abre o modal
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

//Obter o elemento <span> que fecha o modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

//Quando o usuário clicar no botão, abra o modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    ocultar.style.display = ("none");
}

//Quando o usuário clicar em <span> (x), feche o modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    if(ocultar.style = "none"){
        ocultar.style = ("block !important");
    }
}

//Quando o usuário clica em qualquer lugar fora do modal, feche-o
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        ocultar.style = ("block !important");
    }
}
```

Mas o modal está funcionando apenas no primeiro botão. Nos outros botões ele não acontece nada. Já verifiquei o console do Google chrome, e não mostra nada de erro.

Se quiserem dar uma olhada >>> [SITE COM OS BOTÕES](http://www.clinicadepsicologiacontato.com/)

Comment: `if(ocultar.style = "none")` Era pra ser `==`

Comment: Na verdade já está funcionando do jeito que coloquei. Se eu colocar == ele para de funcionar.
O problema real é que ele funciona no primeiro botão da página, e nos outros não!

Comment: Do jeito que você colocou, vai sempre entrar nesse if, e sempre mudar o style do ocultar para none.

Comment: E está faltando `.display` em vários lugares que você usa só `.style`.

Comment: Desculpe amigo, eu acabei de testar suas sugestões, mas não surtiram efeito. 
Você chegou clicar no link? talvez entenda o que quero dizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tem vários botões e cada um abre um modal diferente, é preciso ter em mente que cada botão deve ter um `id` diferente. Portanto, abrir a respectiva modal baseando-se no `id` do botão se torna algo muito ruim, pois você teria que criar um `onclick` para cada botão.

Você não pode ter vários botões ou modais com o mesmo `id`. Isso é errado. Um `id` deve ser único em toda a página para qualquer tipo de elemento.

**O que você deve fazer:**

Pegar o click pela classe do botão e abrir a modal que de alguma forma esteja vinculada a esse botão com essa classe.

**Vinculando cada botão à sua modal:**

Inclua um atributo `data-modal="myModal1"` na tag do botão e altere o `id` também. Por exemplo:

```
<a id="myBtn1" data-modal="myModal1" class="button">Fale comigo</a>
```

E na modal relacionada a esse botão, altere o `id` para:

```
<div id="myModal1">
    MODAL
</div>
```

Com esta sugestão, você está criando um vínculo do botão com a `div` da modal. Faça isso com todos os botões e suas respectivas modais alterando o `id` e o `data-modal` para um valor diferente. Exemplo:

```
<a id="myBtn2" data-modal="myModal2" class="button">Contato</a>

<div id="myModal2">
    MODAL
</div>

....

<a id="myBtn3" data-modal="myModal3" class="button">Contato</a>

<div id="myModal3">
    MODAL
</div>
```

E assim sucessivamente com todos os botões e modais. Assim teremos cada botão e cada modal com um `id` e um `data-modal` únicos.

Feito isso, basta chamar a modal clicando no seu respectivo botão com o código abaixo:

```
var botoes = document.querySelectorAll("a.button");
for(var x=0; x<botoes.length; x++){
   botoes[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal).style.display = "block";
   });
}
```

E para fechar, o código:

```
var fechar = document.querySelectorAll("span.close");
for(var x=0; x<fechar.length; x++){
   fechar[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
   });
}
```

Qualquer dúvida basta chamar. Abs!

Comment: Obrigado. Sua resposta foi muito completa e solucionou meu problema!